# Caching XML responses

Tags: php, xml, zend-framework, caching

We have this API to our ordering system in our Call-Center, that our online-ordering communicates with.
But lots of the requests and responses are the same, more or less static - but the API server generates them, it don't just supply a static file.

What do you suggest as the best approach for caching XML responses? I have had a look at Zend_Cache. But from what i understand, i think it's client/session -based, i would like all clients to take advantage of the same cache.

Also every pageview does a pricerequest for the contents of the basket, what caching do you suggest for this. I think Zend_Cache maybe could come into play here !?

Basicly what i need, is to take the load of the API server, so it has more resources to hanlde price requests, and other requests that changes per request.

**Update: 13. Dec. 2010 10.45**

Request timing

```
2010-12-10T14:43:46+01:00 DEBUG (7): XML GET /ccstatus [0.054742097854614]
2010-12-10T14:43:46+01:00 DEBUG (7): XML GET /storestatus [0.063634157180786]
2010-12-10T14:43:46+01:00 DEBUG (7): XML GET /storestatus [0.062693119049072]
2010-12-10T14:43:46+01:00 DEBUG (7): XML GET /storestatus [0.062756061553955]
2010-12-10T14:43:46+01:00 DEBUG (7): XML GET /storestatus [0.062740087509155]
2010-12-10T14:43:46+01:00 DEBUG (7): XML GET /storelocations [0.065214872360229]
2010-12-10T14:43:46+01:00 DEBUG (7): XML GET /coupons [0.070861101150513]
2010-12-10T14:43:47+01:00 DEBUG (7): XML GET /packagedeals [0.51115489006042]
2010-12-10T14:43:47+01:00 DEBUG (7): XML POST /price [0.065691947937012]
2010-12-10T14:43:47+01:00 DEBUG (7): XML GET /pizzas [0.10685706138611]
2010-12-10T14:43:47+01:00 DEBUG (7): XML GET /bevtypes [0.059874057769775]
2010-12-10T14:43:47+01:00 DEBUG (7): XML GET /bevsizes [0.056848049163818]
2010-12-10T14:43:47+01:00 DEBUG (7): XML GET /items [0.070401191711426]
2010-12-10T14:43:47+01:00 DEBUG (7): XML GET /storestatus [0.062546014785767]
2010-12-10T14:43:47+01:00 DEBUG (7): XML GET /storestatus [0.063254117965698]
2010-12-10T14:43:47+01:00 DEBUG (7): XML GET /storestatus [0.062647104263306]
2010-12-10T14:43:47+01:00 DEBUG (7): XML GET /storestatus [0.062632083892822]
2010-12-10T14:43:47+01:00 DEBUG (7): XML GET /storestatus [0.062486886978149]
2010-12-10T14:43:47+01:00 DEBUG (7): XML GET /items [0.059072017669678]
2010-12-10T14:43:47+01:00 DEBUG (7): XML GET /storestatus [0.062618970870972]
2010-12-10T14:43:48+01:00 DEBUG (7): XML POST /price [0.063409805297852]
```

This is the requests for a single pageview, showing a page of side orders, and the basket contains 2 items.

Based on these times, do you think i will get a considerable difference by caching the data? These times is no-load-at-all, so at high-load the caching could probably come in handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see an obvious way to do much caching on the pricerequest requests that are basket-dependent. These strike me as probably session-based, highly variable, so computing them per-request seems pretty necessary.

The other requests - the "API requests" - if they truly are as static as you suggest, then they seem to be a great candidate for straight-up Zend_Cache with a File or Memcached backend. Just need to figure out an algorithm for generating a unique key for each of the static API requests you wish to cache.

You could even specify an infinite lifetime in the frontend options and run a cron job to repopulate the cache on whatever frequency you think is reasonable enough to keep the content fresh.

Just thinking out loud.

Cheers!

Comment: Great thoughts :) About the price-request, i was thinking saving last response in the session, and only update/refresh the response if any changes is made to the content of the basket. But you're probably right, i could probably store the more or less static requests in a file. I have updated my initial post with a list of how log each request is taking to get from the API

Comment: Right, if the basket hasn't changed, no need to do a new pricerequest. Good catch. ;-)

Comment: Accepted your answer, because i went with the Zend_Cache file and a cron job to update the cache. We immediately saw an 50% drop in load times on the online ordering :) No scientificaly method, just by clicking on link an counting seconds until page was loaded.

Answer (score 4):

`Zend_Cache` is not session-based. It has a [number of backends to store the cached data in](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.cache.backends.html). For instance, you can setup a memcached server on your network and store the XML in there. You could cache by function call or entire page results or by arbitrary keys.

You can find a number of [articles about `Zend_Cache` at Devzone](http://devzone.zend.com/search/results?q=cache)

Another option would be to add a Caching Proxy between your API Server and your clients that transparently handles any requests to your API Server and decides whether to serve a cached response or query the API server. The advantage of this approach is it keeps the caching logic away from your API server. The disadvantage is it needs another server.

Comment: Caching proxies to consider are Varnish (http://www.varnish-cache.org/ ) and Squid (http://www.squid-cache.org/ ).

Comment: Another server *application* but not necessarily another *physical server*.

Comment: @ElYobo I didnt say which, did I? ;)

Comment: No, no, I suppose you didn't :)